# Meteor react Issue with flashing image - shows logged out then logged in

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

UPDATE: after restart it works now. However it stills shows the logged out component first then the logged in one. Why is this because the user is logged in I just refresh the page?

UPDATE 2:
It has gone back to the flashing of the logged out => then then what it should be and then to white again, after no changes just restarting meteor.

UPDATE 3:
So it works then I navigate to this page but not others.It seems because the registration page subscribes to the items collection so that is how it picks it up. I thought it should not refresh the Box component when changing pages and should be subscribed to the items collection from the Box component itself. This page is loaded via flow router and is inputted into the content area of the site see below:

```
import Items from '/imports/collections/items/items.js';



export default class Registration extends TrackerReact(React.Component){

    constructor(){
            super();
            this.state = {
                    subscription: {
                            items: Meteor.subscribe("allStarterItems")
                    }
            }
    }
```

The main page is here, the issues lies within the LeftNavbar area as this contains the boxes:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import LeftNavbar from './LeftNavbar';

export const MainLayout = ({content}) => (

<div className="main-layout">


        <LeftNavbar />

        <div className="right content-page">
                          <main>
                  {content}
            </main> 

        </div>


</div>
)
```

Here is the left navbar page:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import Box from '/imports/ui/left_navbar/Box';

export default class LeftNavbar extends TrackerReact(React.Component){

    constructor(){
     super();   
    }

    render(){       
     return (  
                    <div className="left side-menu">    
                            <div className="body rows scroll-y">    
                                    <div className="sidebar-inner ">
                                            <Box />
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                    </div>   
         ) 
    }
 }
```

---

Hey everyone I have an issue in my project.

I have an area where I have a stack of images stacked on top of each other and are overlayed. I know the css etc work as I have it on another page just not loading from a db.

Here the the file that checks if the user is logged in or not to decide what component to render:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import BoxSignedIn from     '/BoxSignedIn';
import BoxSignedOut from '/BoxSignedOut';


 export default class Box extends TrackerReact(React.Component){

    constructor(){
     super();   
    }



    render(){
        var layout;
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            layout = <BoxSignedIn />;
        } else {
            layout = <BoxSignedOut />;
        }


     return (   
                layout                          
            ) 

    }
}
```

Here is the component that is loaded. However when I reload the page it shows the logged out component for a split second, then it shows nothing. On the source of the page it shows no src from the images. In the console it sometimes shows 2 of the image sources, sometimes 3

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
import Items from '/imports/collections/items/items.js';



export default class BoxSignedIn extends TrackerReact(React.Component){

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
                subscription: {
                        items: Meteor.subscribe("allStarterItems")
                },
                layers: {
                    layer1: Meteor.user().profile.layer.1,
                    layer2: Meteor.user().profile.layer.2,
                    layer3: Meteor.user().profile.layer.3
                }
        }
    }


    componentWillUnmount(){
        this.state.subscription.items.stop();
    }



    getItemSource(itemKey){


        var itemer = Items.findOne({key: itemKey});
        if(!itemer){
                return "";
        }else{
                console.log(itemer.srcEntire); // shows src correctly
                return itemer.srcEntire;
        }
    }


    render(){   

     return (   

        <div className="media"  >
                <div className="Area">
                    <div className="container-on-top box-small" >
                        <img id="layer1" className="on-top img-responsive center-block on-top" name="layer1" src={this.getItemSource(this.state.layers.layer1)} />
                        <img id="layer2" className="on-top img-responsive center-block on-top" name="layer2" src={this.getItemSource(this.state.layers.layer2)} />
                        <img id="layer3" className="on-top img-responsive center-block on-top" name="layer3" src={this.getItemSource(this.state.layers.layer3)} />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>    

            ) 
    }
}
```

Comment: facing the same issue here. Are you rendering server side? like with flow-router-ssr?

Comment: Nope not rendering server side. I am new to Meteor so have not looked into server side rendering as of yet.

Comment: not sure if this might help you but how about adding a Meteor.loggingIn() method somewhere there. It appears that the logging in is not completed by the time the logic to check if a user is logged in runs

Comment: you can check if Meteor.loggingIn(), if so, display loading, if not then you check if they are logged in or not.